# Cannot get the data in the required fragment

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

I am trying to pass the data from *NgoSignup1Fragment* to *NgoSignup2Fragment* but i am getting null in NgoSignup2Fragment as you can see  [Debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0MRD.jpg), I didn't know what's the issue if anyone would help it will helpful for me.

```
class NgoSignup1Fragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var communicator: Communicator
private lateinit var nextBtn: Button

private var name : TextInputEditText ?=null
private var mail : TextInputEditText ?=null
private var phone : TextInputEditText ?=null
private var add :TextInputEditText ?=null
private var pinCode :TextInputEditText ?=null
private var password :TextInputEditText ?=null
private var confirmPassword :TextInputEditText ?=null

private val emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+"

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,

): View? {
    val v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ngo_signup1_fragment, container, false)
    communicator = activity as Communicator

    nextBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_ngosignup1_next)

    name = v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_name)
    mail = v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_mail)
    phone = v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_phone)
    add = v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_address)
    pinCode = v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_pincode)
    password =v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_password)
    confirmPassword =v?.findViewById(R.id.et_ngosignup_confirmpassword)


    nextBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val orgName = name?.text.toString().trim()
        val orgMail = mail?.text.toString().trim()
        val orgPhone = phone?.text.toString().trim()
        val officeAdd = add?.text.toString().trim()
        val orgPinCode = pinCode?.text.toString().trim()
        val orgPass = password?.text.toString().trim()
        val confirmPass=confirmPassword?.text.toString().trim()
        if (orgName.isEmpty()) {
            name?.error = "Please provide organisation's name"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (orgMail.isEmpty()) {
            mail?.error = "Mail cannot be empty"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (orgPhone.isEmpty()) {
            phone?.error = "Enter your phone number"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (officeAdd.isEmpty()) {
            add?.error = "Address cannot be empty"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (orgPinCode.isEmpty()) {
            name?.error = "Name cannot be empty"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (orgPass.isEmpty()){
            password?.error = "Password cannot be empty"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (!(orgMail.matches(emailPattern.toRegex()))) {
            mail?.error = "Invalid email"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if (!(isValidPassword(orgPass))) {
            password?.error = "Password format is invalid"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }
        if(orgPass != confirmPass){
            confirmPassword?.error = "Passwords doesn't match"
            markButtonDisable(nextBtn)
        }else{
           communicator.passDataCom(orgName,orgMail,orgPhone,officeAdd,orgPinCode,orgPass)
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
                ?.replace(
                    R.id.fragment_container1,
                    NgoSignup2Fragment()
                )?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
        }

        //this opens up the sign up 2 page
        //Put the value
        //Put the value


    }

    return v
}
private fun isValidPassword(password: String): Boolean {
    val passwordREGEX = Pattern.compile(
        "^" +
                "(?=.*[0-9])" +         //at least 1 digit
                "(?=.*[a-z])" +         //at least 1 lower case letter
                "(?=.*[A-Z])" +         //at least 1 upper case letter
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +      //any letter
                "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +    //at least 1 special character
                "(?=\\S+$)" +           //no white spaces
                ".{8,}" +               //at least 8 characters
                "$"
    )
    return passwordREGEX.matcher(password).matches()
}
private fun markButtonDisable(b:Button){
    b.isEnabled =false
    b.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.theme_button_disabled))
}}
```

my interface which i am using to pass data :

```
interface Communicator {
fun passDataCom(
    orgName: String,
    orgMail: String,
    orgPhone: String,
    officeAdd: String,
    orgPin: String,
    orgPass: String
)}
```

This is MainActivity where the string values are passed Till here all the variables values are correct

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),Communicator {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    /*This part of the code is used to set the default theme as the theme was set to the splash screen before setting the main activity layout
       remove the comment tag for adding the logic*/
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Samarpan)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    addFragment()

}

private fun addFragment() {
    val userSignInLayout= LoginFragment()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container1,userSignInLayout).commit()
}

override fun passDataCom(
    orgName: String,
    orgMail: String,
    orgPhone: String,
    officeAdd: String,
    orgPin: String,
    orgPass: String
) {
    val bundle=Bundle()
    bundle.putString("Name",orgName)
    bundle.putString("Mail",orgMail)
    bundle.putString("Phone",orgPhone)
    bundle.putString("Address",officeAdd)
    bundle.putString("PinCode",orgPin)
    bundle.putString("Password",orgPass)

    val transaction=this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val ngoSignUp2 = NgoSignup2Fragment()
    ngoSignUp2.arguments = bundle
    transaction. Commit()
}}
```

This is the fragment where i want to send the values but i m getting null values to all the variables .

```
class NgoSignup2Fragment : Fragment(){

private var v : View?=null
private var btnNgoRegister: Button?=null
private var tilCategoryOthers:TextInputLayout?=null
private var etCategoryOthers:TextInputEditText?=null


private var orgName:String =""
private var orgMail:String =""
private var orgPhone:String =""
private var officeAdd:String =""
private var orgPin:String =""
private var orgPass:String =""
private var category:String=""

private lateinit var registerAuth: FirebaseAuth


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ngo_signup2_fragment,container,false)
    btnNgoRegister=v?.findViewById(R.id.btnNgoRegister)
    tilCategoryOthers=v?.findViewById(R.id.til_category_others)
    etCategoryOthers=v?.findViewById(R.id.et_category_others)

    val organisationTypes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.organisation_type)
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),R.layout.dropdown_item,organisationTypes)
    val autoCompleteTV= v?.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.ngosignup_select_orgtype_items)
    autoCompleteTV?.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

    category=autoCompleteTV?.text.toString().trim()

    registerAuth= Firebase.auth

    orgName= arguments?.getString("Name").toString().trim()
    orgMail= arguments?.getString("Mail").toString().trim()
    orgPhone=arguments?.getString("Phone").toString().trim()
    officeAdd=arguments?.getString("Address").toString().trim()
    orgPin=arguments?.getString("PinCode").toString().trim()
    orgPass=arguments?.getString("Password").toString().trim()

    btnNgoRegister?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity, orgName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if(category == "Others"){
            //get the category from the user of the type he is from other than the list
            btnNgoRegister?.isEnabled=false
            tilCategoryOthers?.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            category=etCategoryOthers?.text.toString()
            btnNgoRegister?.isEnabled=true
        }
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        try{
            registerAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(orgMail,orgPass)
                .addOnCompleteListener{ task->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        val ngo: FirebaseUser? =registerAuth.currentUser
                        Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            "Thank You! for choosing us",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                         ).show()
                        val documentReference : DocumentReference =db.collection("users").document(
                            ngo?.uid ?: ""
                     )
                        val ngoInfo :MutableMap<String,Any> = HashMap()
                        ngoInfo["Full Name"]= orgName
                        ngoInfo["Email"]= orgMail
                        ngoInfo["PhoneNumber"]=orgPhone
                        ngoInfo["Address"]=officeAdd
                        ngoInfo["Pin Code"]=orgPin
                        ngoInfo["isDonor"]="0"
                        // add the value of the org type from the dropdown and upload document work
                        documentReference.set(ngoInfo).addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "User data for $orgName was collected successfully ")
                        }.addOnFailureListener{ e ->
                            Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Error adding data", e)
                        }
                }else{
                        Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            task.exception!!.message.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
            }
    }
    catch(e :Exception){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fields cannot be empty $e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    }
    return v
}}
```

Comment: Because you are adding `NgoSignup2Fragment` twice . once inside `passDataCom` and once after that ..For The second one you did not passed any Bundle ..
Do not make transaction  inside data class thats bad practice . Just return the bundle from data class if you need and make transaction inside fragment only once .

Comment: @ADM can you please elaborate a little more , I didn't get it Thanks in Advance